# How to return a Pandas Dataframe after reading .zip file from unix box

Tags: pandas, paramiko

I have a file abc.zip present at some unix server .
I need to read the contents of the abc.zip file and store the result in pandas dataframe

I tried reading the file from unix server using paramiko , but was unable to store the result in pandas dataframe .

```
import paramiko
ssh_client=paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh_client.connect(hostname='xyx',username='abc',password='qwe')
#using unzip is creating 3 lines which are not needed in dataframe , so 
#using tail.
stdin,stdout,stderr=ssh_client.exec_command("unzip -c path/abc.zip | tail -n +3")
#created an empty list.
unix_file =[]
#read the data from stdout and appended in list
for line in stdout.readlines():
    unix_file.append(line)
#tried creating Dataframe by iterating over unix_file list
df = pd.DataFrame([sub.split("\t") for sub in unix_file])
```

I expected the Dataframe with header and data , but the actual o/p i got is Dataframe is considering Columns as part of data , and by default assigning [0,1,2,] values as columns .

Any better way to read a .zip file and handling tab-separated list would be helpful .

Comment: You didn't tell us anything about the format of your .zip file contents + Are you able to construct the `DataFrame` from a **local** ZIP file?

Comment: the content of .zip file is a single txt file ... Yes , In local machine  i am able to read zip file using read_csv with sep='\t' of pandas ... But , reading content of zip file on unix host server and converting it to clean dataframe is issue i m facing

Comment: Show us your code to process a local ZIP using `read_csv`.

Comment: Well that was just 2 lines of code .... 
`patht = r'D:\ITG\abc.zip'
pyitgdf = pd.read_csv(patht,sep='\t',header=0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some workaround , might not be the best way , but its working.

'

```
stdin,stdout,stderr=ssh_client.exec_command("unzip -c /ges2/data/TransactionData/ITG/Well_extract_20120406_test.zip | tail -n +3")
unix_file =[]
for line in stdout.readlines():
    unix_file.append(line)

output = [line.rstrip() for line in unix_file]

col = output[0].split('\t')

data = output[1:]

pyitgdf = pd.DataFrame([sub.split('\t') for sub in data], columns = col)
print(pyitgdf.head(5))
```

`

I know there is some clean way to achieve this , but not getting it

Answer (score 0):

If `read_csv` works for you, use it with your remote data:

```
stdin,stdout,stderr = ssh_client.exec_command("unzip -c path/abc.zip | tail -n +3")
pyitgdf = pd.read_csv(stdout, sep='\t', header=0)
```

Comment: Sorry, its not working ...
getting the error  `  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 545, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
pandas.errors.EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file `